# Having a maximum of one Android Notification at any point

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android app that is supposed to inform the user of events that have happened. I have successfully created the code that allows for me to create the Android notifications and display them to the user etc.

The problem I am having is I should only ever have one notification. In the event that a previous notification hasn't been cleared yet, I would like to be able to access it (this is primarily to allow me to check the number property), so I can set the appropriate number property on the new notification. Unfortunately I have not been able to identify how I would go about retreiving a previous notification if it still exists. I don't particularly need anything more than the number from the notification as I will be running code that will cancel that notification prior to creating the new one.

I do have the ID for the notification that would have been raised (if any).

So in summary, how can I retrieve a previous notification, so I can get the number from it.

Comment: The ID is given by you, in creating a notification, right? If you need no more than one notification, you just use the same ID to create any notification in your app and only one notification will be presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain why @xandy wrote a comment instead of an answer, but the approach described is correct.

Simply call `notify()` with your new `Notification` object and the same ID as before. If the `Notification` is still on-screen, it will be updated with your new `number`. If the `Notification` was cleared by the user, or was never there in the first place, your new `Notification` will be displayed. You can see that in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1) -- just click the top button twice.

Note that Android 3.0 appears to have deprecated the `number` -- I cannot get it to show up on a XOOM, for example.

Comment: The problem is that if I had two events and a new event is to be notified I want to display three if the old notification hadn't been cleared or one if the old notification had been cleared. Is there any way to achieve this?
Also thank you for the information regarding Android 3.0, thats good to know and I'll have to keep that in mind.

Comment: @Satal: "Is there any way to achieve this?" -- if by "three" you mean "three icons", please don't do that. If by "three" you mean "set `number` to `3`", you will need to keep track of that yourself. You can get control when the user clears the `Notification`, and you know when you cancel it yourself.

Comment: My apologies, yes I meant setting the number property to 3, which I believe then puts the number 3 on the icon for the notification. When you say that I can get control when the user clears the notification how do you mean?

Comment: @Satal: You can specify a separate `PendingIntent` to be invoked when the user cancels the `Notification`.